# regex for phone number starting with + (optional) and whitespace allowed

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex that will match any value :

- that can start or not with a +
- that is composed only of numbers
- whitespaces are allowed after the + (if present) and between any set of numbers
- must contains at least one number

I've done the following regex `^[+]{0,1}[0-9 ]+$`, that is covering the first 3 cases but not the last one as the following values `"+ "` or `"   "` match the regex and this is not what I want as they contain no number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start the pattern with an optional `+` followed by optional spaces. Then first match a single digit, followed by matching optional spaces or digits.

```regex
^[+]? *[0-9][0-9 ]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5j6zsj/1)

If the leading spaces can only be present where there is a `+`:, the `+` and spaces can be optional:

```
^(?:[+] *)?[0-9][0-9 ]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rd3ycB/1)

Comment: hmm I think maybe OP doesn't want to allow spaces at the beginning unless followed by a `+`?

Comment: @Chase In that case I have added another pattern to make the `+` followed by 0+ whitespaces optional.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming groups of numbers are separated by spaces:

```
^\+?( *\d+)+$
```

Notes:

- Spaces optionally introduce one or more digits
- Replaced `{0,1}` with `?`
- Replaced `[0-9]` with `\d`